# http-kit & compojure on clojure, # symbol in get url query failing

Tags: http, clojure, get, http-kit

I am having trouble getting the http get query prams due to the # symbol being part of the query string.

Ideally the external party should have URL encoded the params but that is not the case.

So when I call the :query-string on the received request it works fine up to that point.

Is there anyway I can mitigate this problem?

I have gone through the http-kit docs and the ring doc since http-kit conforms to the ring spec but to no avail. If anyone can point me in the right direction i will be grateful.

Comment: if your clients use browser then it is impossible because browsers never send anything after #

Comment: Thank you Mavbozo, but they aren't using a browser its part of an RPC